# Fetching data from API and using it in JSX is giving string output to the html tag

Tags: html, reactjs, api, jsx

I am fetching data from an API whose response is:

```
{
       "name": "family: woman, woman, girl, girl",
       "unicode": "1F469 200D 1F469 200D 1F467 200D 1F467",
       "html": "&#128105;&zwj;&#128105;&zwj;&#128103;&zwj;&#128103;"
}
```

and now I want to use this value in my code using JSX:

```
import React from 'react';
function Card(props) {
    return (
            <div>
                <p>{props.html}</p>
            </div>
    );
}

export default Card;
```

**Output I am getting on my page**
`&#128105;&zwj;&#128105;&zwj;&#128103;&zwj;&#128103;`

**Required Output**
‍‍‍

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.html }} />
```

---

**Codesandbox demo**

[image: Edit hardcore-hugle-l53he]

---

**Reference**

[dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
import React from 'react';
import Parser from "html-react-parser";
function Card(props) {
    return (
            <div>
                <p>{Parser(props.html)}</p>
            </div>
    );
}

export default Card
```